# virsh: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libvirt.so.0: undefined symbol: g_canonicalize_filename

Tags: libvirt, virsh

I am newbie and trying to run below command on bare metal server and getting below error and not sure what is the issue, please help me ?

Command >> virsh

Error >> virsh: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libvirt.so.0: undefined symbol: g_canonicalize_filename

Command >> virsh

Expectation >> give some valid response for this tool

Comment: which OS & what version (eg., `uname -a` and/or `lsb_release -a`)? You might be missing libraries that need to be installed, but the actual libs & commands would vary depending on OS & version. Worst cast scenario would be that you're on an OS/version that's too old and might not provide that specific call, possibly requiring an OS update and/or upgrade.